# Mongodb TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to query a user balance by using the accountAddress and contractAddress as inputs. Here is the command I am running:

```
return await mongoInterface.erc721BalancesModel.find({accountAddress: publicAddress, contractAddress: filterNFTContracts })
```

**Here are the inputs from a console.log, showing that it is not undefined:**

```
let test = {accountAddress: publicAddress, contractAddress: filterNFTContracts }
                console.log(test)
{
  accountAddress: '0x1262C73929D0D6759203fd3090F3A8A171dDF66A',
  contractAddress: '0xf3c9B7A97Eba579f5c234F79108331F5513c9741'
}
```

As you can see, I am passing in the same exact input into both the .find() command and mongoDB compass. MongoDB compass is able to find the object.

[image]

**The error that I am receiving is:**

> (node:35664) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read
> property 'find' of undefined
> at Function.findAllERC721ByOwner (file:///G:/dapps/cosmicflask-api/server/lib/api-helper.js:272:65)
> at Function.handleApiRequest (file:///G:/dapps/cosmicflask-api/server/lib/api-helper.js:91:47)
> at file:///G:/dapps/cosmicflask-api/server/lib/api-interface.js:58:40
> at runMicrotasks ()
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5) (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created) (node:35664)
> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
> error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
> without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
> with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise
> rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see
> https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode).
> (rejection id: 2) (node:35664) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled
> promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections
> that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a
> non-zero exit code.

**mongo-interface.js:**

```
  import mongoose from 'mongoose'
  const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

  const ERC721BalancesSchema = new Schema({
  contractAddress: {
    type: String, index: true
  },
  accountAddress: {
    type: String, index: true
  } ,
  tokenIds: {
    type: [Number]
  },
  lastUpdatedAt:{
    type: Number
  }

})
...
export var erc721BalancesModel
async initModels(){

this.erc721BalancesModel = this.connection.model('erc721_balances', ERC721BalancesSchema)
}
```

**findAllERC721ByOwner:**

```
if(inputData.requestType == 'ERC721_balance_by_owner'){
                let inputParameters = inputData.input
                let results = await APIHelper.findAllERC721ByOwner(inputParameters.publicAddress, inputParameters.filterNFTcontracts  , wolfpackInterface)
                return {success:true, input: inputParameters, output: results  }
            }

static async findAllERC721ByOwner(publicAddress,filterNFTContracts, mongoInterface){
            publicAddress = AppHelper.toChecksumAddress(publicAddress)
            console.log(publicAddress, filterNFTContracts)

            if(filterNFTContracts && filterNFTContracts.length > 0){

                // filterNFTContracts = filterNFTContracts.map( x => AppHelper.toChecksumAddress(x) )
                filterNFTContracts = AppHelper.toChecksumAddress(filterNFTContracts)

                let test = {accountAddress: publicAddress, contractAddress: filterNFTContracts }
                console.log(test)


                return await mongoInterface.erc721BalancesModel.find({accountAddress: publicAddress, contractAddress: filterNFTContracts })
            }

            return await mongoInterface.erc721BalancesModel.find({accountAddress: publicAddress })
        }
```

Comment: You are finding on `erc721BalancesModel`. Shouldn't that be `erc721_Balances`?

Comment: See my latest edit for information on the mongointerface

Comment: Can we see the `findAllERC721ByOwner` function?

Comment: Is mongo-interface.js included as a module? If so what is exported? How is `this` supposed to be assigned to `mongoInterface`?

Comment: Joe, mongoInterface is pulled in as a module. I updated it  to include the export function.